# Frequency of vibration in a wire driven by a tuning fork

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, wavefunction, acoustics

A tuning fork of frequency 480 Hz is used to vibrate a sonometer wire having natural frequency 416 Hz. The wire will vibrate with what frequency?
My textbook gives the answer as 480Hz, but i don't understand how. I feel normal modes will set up in the wire. Maybe some superposition of the normal modes will result in wire vibrating with 480Hz.

Comment: These might help - [Modes of vibration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769243/37364) and [A conceptual question about waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/796760/37364)